# Uninitialized string offset in for loop

Tags: php

I know there's already some questions related to this, but it seems none answered my real problem...

Here's the loop:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tabela); $i++) {
      echo('<tr>');
      echo('<td>' . $tabela[$i]['de'] . '</td>');
      echo('<td>' . $tabela[$i]['para'] . '</td>');
      echo('<td>' . $tabela[$i]['principio'] . '</td>');
      echo('<td>' . $tabela[$i]['descricao'] . '</td>');
      echo('<td>' . $tabela[$i]['data'] . '</td>');
      echo('</tr>');
    }
```

This gives me `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0`

Obviously, the position 0 exists, and goes till the second.

Anyone can help me? Ty! :D

EDIT:

PRINT_R:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 96
        [de] => Robert
        [para] => Felipe Bueno
        [principio] => Qualidade, como busca permanente.
        [descricao] => um bom rapaz
        [data] => 21/32/1321
        [status] => Aprovação Pendente
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 97
        [de] => Robertinho
        [para] => Felipe dos Santos Bueno
        [principio] => Agilidade, como dinâmica de ação.
        [descricao] => nois
        [data] => 21/32/1421
        [status] => Aprovação Pendente
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 99
        [de] => tetyane
        [para] => Felipe Santos Bueno
        [principio] => Sustentabilidade, como forma de crescimento.
        [descricao] => erererere
        [data] => 21/32/1321
        [status] => Aprovação Pendente
    )

)
```

Comment: Just because `$tabela[$i]` exists doesn't mean `$tabela[$i]['otherstuff']` exists.

Comment: where is your $tabela?

Comment: _Obviously, the position 0 exists, and goes till the second._ Not according to PHP. Add a `print_r($tablea)` to prove what is actually there in that array.

Comment: `Obviously, the position 0 exists` not really, arrays in php can be non-zero length without index `0`

Comment: @RiggsFolly as it seems, there is a 0 position...